# syntax highlighting plugin for wordpress 3.2.1

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried some syntax highlighting plugins for my wordpres site(v 3.2.1) but those are not working. Can you suggestion one wp plugin that works for wordpress 3.2.1

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use SyntaxHighlighter Evolved which works perfect (I have the latest version of wordpress). http://www.viper007bond.com/wordpress-plugins/syntaxhighlighter/

You should be able to find it in the wordpress plugin library

Answer (score 0):

Syntax Highlighter doesnt work on my site after the 3.2.1 upgrade. I am using the 3.1.3 version Site : blog.ganeshzone.net